# InnoDB: Why does transaction wait for IX lock when it already has a X lock?

Tags: innodb, deadlock

I'm getting a deadlock in my code. Txn 1 is waiting for a lock to be granted which is held currently by Txn 2. Txn 2 already has a X lock but still is requesting for a IX lock.

Both the transactions run an Insert query using [ActiveRecord import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import).
The deadlock section in `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` gives me:

```
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 7431 page no 178 n bits 80 index PRIMARY of table `company_ebdb`.`user_metrics` trx id 51241147861 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

 *** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 7431 page no 178 n bits 80 index PRIMARY of table `company_ebdb`.`user_metrics` trx id 51241147863 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 7431 page no 178 n bits 80 index PRIMARY of table `company_ebdb`.`user_metrics` trx id 51241147863 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;
```

My question is why does Txn 2 need an IX lock if it already holds an X lock?

Update 1:
Here is the complete LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK section:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2022-09-02 16:11:22 0x149b2c2ef700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 51241147861, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 8 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 5 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 8423321, OS thread handle 22689954051840, query id 19045173171 172.31.15.180 mitdb4dm1n update
INSERT INTO `user_metrics` (`id`,`current`,`total`,`my_type`,`owner_id`,`owner_type`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) VALUES (NULL,175,175,0,108840,'OwnerName','2022-09-02 16:11:22','2022-09-02 16:11:22'),(NULL,100,151,0,108841,'OwnerName','2022-09-02 16:11:22','2022-09-02 16:11:22'),(NULL,169,169,0,112780,'OwnerName','2022-09-02 16:11:22','2022-09-02 16:11:22'),(NULL,202,217,0,112781,'OwnerName','2022-09-02 16:11:22','2022-09-02 16:11:22'),(NULL,26,62,0,112782,'OwnerName','2022-09-02 16:11:22','2022-09-02 16:11:22'),(NULL,169,169,0,112794,'OwnerName','2022-09-02 16:11:22','2022-09-02 16:11:22'),(NULL,177,217,0,112795,'OwnerName','2022-09-02 16:11:22','2022-09-02 16:11:22'),(NULL,28,62,0,112796,'OwnerName','2022-09-02 16:11:22','2022-09-02 16:11:22'),(NULL,140,140,0,114162,'OwnerName','2022-09-02 16:11:22','2022-09-02 16:11:22'),(NULL,64,64,0,114163,'OwnerName','2022-09-0
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 7431 page no 178 n bits 80 index PRIMARY of table `company_ebdb`.`user_metrics` trx id 51241147861 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 51241147863, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
7 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 5 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 8424694, OS thread handle 22656693761792, query id 19045173179 172.31.4.27 mitdb4dm1n update
INSERT INTO `user_metrics` (`id`,`current`,`total`,`my_type`,`owner_id`,`owner_type`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) VALUES (NULL,1,89,0,137623,'OwnerName','2022-09-02 16:11:22','2022-09-02 16:11:22'),(NULL,0,3,0,137624,'OwnerName','2022-09-02 16:11:22','2022-09-02 16:11:22'),(NULL,178,182,0,137635,'OwnerName','2022-09-02 16:11:22','2022-09-02 16:11:22'),(NULL,77,129,0,137645,'OwnerName','2022-09-02 16:11:22','2022-09-02 16:11:22'),(NULL,5,14,0,137646,'OwnerName','2022-09-02 16:11:22','2022-09-02 16:11:22'),(NULL,0,87,0,137656,'OwnerName','2022-09-02 16:11:22','2022-09-02 16:11:22'),(NULL,0,11,0,137657,'OwnerName','2022-09-02 16:11:22','2022-09-02 16:11:22'),(NULL,71,71,0,146601,'OwnerName','2022-09-02 16:11:22','2022-09-02 16:11:22'),(NULL,71,71,0,146616,'OwnerName','2022-09-02 16:11:22','2022-09-02 16:11:22'),(NULL,39,64,0,146631,'OwnerName','2022-09-02 16:11:22','2022-0
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 7431 page no 178 n bits 80 index PRIMARY of table `company_ebdb`.`user_metrics` trx id 51241147863 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 7431 page no 178 n bits 80 index PRIMARY of table `company_ebdb`.`user_metrics` trx id 51241147863 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

Update 2:
Create table output for the table involved:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_metrics` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `current` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `my_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `owner_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `owner_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_user_metrics_on_owner_type_and_owner_id_and_my_type` (`owner_type`,`owner_id`,`my_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1167 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table involved.  (Or at least provide all indexes.)

Comment: Updated the queUpdated the question with the output for create table. There is only one table involved and it has one index.

Comment: @Shreyas i am also facing same issue. Did you find any solution? i have posted my deadlock question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76376549/unable-to-find-cause-of-deadlock

Comment: @user3247895 I ended up updating my code in a way that ensure there are no 2 writes happening at the same time, that solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:

Live with it.  But do catch the error and replay the INSERT.

Plan B:

Try this.  (I have no confidence that it will help):

You have two Unique keys (the PK is one).  Let's switch them around, to the following.  (It assumes you can change all three columns to `NOT NULL`.)

```
PRIMARY KEY(`owner_type`,`owner_id`,`my_type`),
INDEX(id)
```

Rationale:

- Two Unique keys leads to two things being locked, and more than twice the likelihood of a conflict.
- Having the data clustered in the order that is beneficial to the query will speed up the query, hence making it more likely to finish before conflicting with another connection.

I doubt if either of these will be sufficient to *prevent* deadlocks.  But they *may* decrease the frequency of deadlocks.  Hence, plan doing Plan A, too.

Comment: Can you give some reasoning on why you think switching the primary key and index might help?

Comment: @Shreyas - I added a Rationale.