# Unable to find cause of deadlock

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, hibernate, jpa

We are using JPA(hibernate) with mysql innodb with following code which is giving deadlock:

```
EntityManager em = threadContextProvider.currentThreadContext().getEm();
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO user_config values ");
        for(int i = 0; i < sortedUsers.size(); i++) {
            query.append(i == 0 ? "" : ",")
                    .append("( null, :userId")
                    .append(i)
                    .append(" , :appId , :devicePlatform")
                    .append(i)
                    .append(", :winningBalance, :payer, :ratedOnAppStore , :ratedOnPlayStore , :gamesEligibilityCount , now() , now() ) ");
        }
        query.append("ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE games_eligibility_count = games_eligibility_count + :gamesEligibilityCount"); //not updating platform

        Query q = em.createNativeQuery(query.toString())
                .setParameter("appId", updateDataList.getAppId())
                .setParameter("gamesEligibilityCount", 1)
                .setParameter("payer", 0)
                .setParameter("winningBalance", "0.00")
                .setParameter("ratedOnAppStore", 0)
                .setParameter("ratedOnPlayStore", 0);
        for(int i = 0; i < sortedUsers.size(); i++) {
            String platform = sortedUsers.get(i).getPlatform() == null ? null : sortedUsers.get(i).getPlatform().name();
            q = q.setParameter("userId" + i, sortedUsers.get(i).getUserId())
                    .setParameter("devicePlatform" + i, platform);
        }
        return q.executeUpdate();
```

**We want to understand why deadlock is happening and how to prevent it?**

Deadlock log from DB is:

> LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
> ------------------------
> 2023-05-30 09:14:20 70395844200144
> *** (1) TRANSACTION:
> TRANSACTION 3986311343, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
> mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
> LOCK WAIT 8 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 5 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
> MySQL thread id 2172920, OS thread handle 70396323890896, query id 707353290 10.0.44.95 root update
> INSERT INTO user_config values ( null, '12a0638f-10ae-43a6-9fad-9b3d9e419b22' , 'onjoyridehpg.carrom' ,
> 'Android', '0.00', 0, 0 , 0 , 1 , now() , now() ) ,( null,
> '749bd96f-b9d8-40fc-a100-a098a2b98e46' , 'onjoyridehpg.carrom' ,
> 'Android', '0.00', 0, 0 , 0 , 1 , now() , now() ) ,( null,
> 'baa3e214-245a-4d3b-9b53-08e38073d3f0' , 'onjoyridehpg.carrom' ,
> 'Android', '0.00', 0, 0 , 0 , 1 , now() , now() ) ON DUPLICATE KEY
> UPDATE games_eligibility_count = games_eligibility_count + 1
>
> ```
> *** (1) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
> RECORD LOCKS space id 440 page no 53761 n bits 88 index PRIMARY of table `unclassified_data_prod`.`user_config` trx id 3986311343
> ```
>
> lock_mode X
> Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
> 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;
>
> ```
> *** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
> RECORD LOCKS space id 440 page no 53761 n bits 88 index PRIMARY of table `unclassified_data_prod`.`user_config` trx id 3986311343
> ```
>
> lock_mode X insert intention waiting
> Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
> 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;
>
> ```
> *** (2) TRANSACTION:
> TRANSACTION 3986311346, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
> mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
> LOCK WAIT 7 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 5 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
> MySQL thread id 2172921, OS thread handle 70396935145168, query id 707353300 10.0.44.95 root update
> INSERT INTO user_config values ( null, '6bf4574b-0e14-43c0-a1ed-61bbf42ba0a7' , 'onjoyridehpg.carrom' ,
> ```
>
> 'Android', '0.00', 0, 0 , 0 , 1 , now() , now() ) ,( null,
> 'bf52c651-5c4e-4405-ae2f-b7b567bfc9d9' , 'onjoyridehpg.carrom' ,
> 'Android', '0.00', 0, 0 , 0 , 1 , now() , now() ) ON DUPLICATE KEY
> UPDATE games_eligibility_count = games_eligibility_count + 1
>
> ```
> *** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
> RECORD LOCKS space id 440 page no 53761 n bits 88 index PRIMARY of table `unclassified_data_prod`.`user_config` trx id 3986311346
> ```
>
> lock_mode X
> Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
> 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;
>
> ```
> *** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
> RECORD LOCKS space id 440 page no 53761 n bits 88 index PRIMARY of table `unclassified_data_prod`.`user_config` trx id 3986311346
> ```
>
> lock_mode X insert intention waiting
> Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
> 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;
>
> ```
> *** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
> ------------
> TRANSACTIONS
> ------------
> Trx id counter 3986637053
> Purge done for trx's n:o < 3986637047 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
> History list length 64
> LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
> ```

Comment: Multiple Threads try to insert or update the same rows in the **user_config** table at the same time. There is no quick fix for that. You need to try different approaches for InnoDB.

Comment: You have two processes likely dealing with overlapping data, both trying to shove it all in as one transaction. Upsert is a problem here as your 'insert or update' has to wait for the lock to release on the row even if it doesn't even need to really update it (your posts make it seem like a proof of concept, with the other just updating a 'updated on' date). You can try ordering your data so that the locks are obtained deterministically which might help slightly,  reevaluating the logic and/or going with a pure Insert or do nothing approach, or expecting this to occur and retry when it does.

Comment: i think i have used ordered data only. plz observe that i am using sortedUsers.
.

Comment: your posts make it seem like a proof of concept, with the other just updating a 'updated on' date  -> updated that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76376472/select-statement-returning-null-after-insert-on-duplicate-key-update-stateme

Comment: I'm sure you can think of data sets and timing cases where sorting won't help. You will have to analyze what is being done exactly - maybe log the SQL issued and replay it to see how the overlap causes deadlocks and what your application might to about it. Something like limiting the size of your transactions, ordering slightly differently, or even the details of the indexes and what is being locked - what is index PRIMARY of table user_config? If that is your Pk column, do you really need that one?